# « Regardez-moi ça » : que fait ici ce possessif ?

Tags: origine-ou-raison, constructions, possessif

J'ai pris cet exemple mais il y a d'autres usages très idiomatiques construits sur le même principe (« Oh mais arrêtez de le taquiner, vous allez *me* le vexer ! »).

Que fait ici ce possessif ?

Est-ce une structure calquée sur une autre langue ?

Je comprends intuitivement le sens par pratique de la langue mais je ne serais pas capable d'en donner l'origine ou l'explication à qui que ce soit...

Comment: Qu'est ce qui vous fait dire qu'il s'agit d'un possessif ?

Comment: @GAMPUB Si c'est plus clair, j'entends par là *Quel est ici le rôle du mot "moi" si ce n'est pas d'indiquer la possession ?*

Comment: Comme l'indique la réponse choisie, le nom classique est datif éthique. Datif au sens de bénéficiaire (différent de possesseur). Une sorte d'extension des constructions comme : *je te fais la vaisselle* (je fais la vaisselle à ta place ou pour toi, pas forcément **ta** vaisselle).

Comment: @GAMPUB En effet, j'ai approuvé cette excellente réponse d'ailleurs, mais la formulation initiale de la question pouvait difficilement prendre en compte les éléments fournis *ultérieurement* en réponse... qu'en pensez *Who*, docteur ? ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il s'agit du [*pronom d'intérêt/explétif*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2927) (ou *[datif éthique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/datif)/dativus ethicus*). Avec la langue *familière*, il s'agit du pronom de 1ère ou 2ème personne employé de manière explétive pour marquer l'intérêt du locuteur ou attirer l'attention de l'interlocuteur sur l'action, respectivement :

> Regardez-moi cette misère (Thérive, *Sans âme*)
>  Tu vous lâches ça, le temps d'éternuer (Zola, *L'Assommoir*)
>  Avez-vous vu comme je
>   te vous lui ai craché à la figure ? (Hugo, *Les Misérables*)
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Boeck, exemples tirés de
>   §672e, *sur les formes conjointes objets indirects.* ]

On élabore sur la fonction grammaticale à la *BDL* :

> La fonction grammaticale du pronom d'intérêt pose problème. Certains
>   grammairiens le considèrent comme un complément indirect puisque la
>   forme du pronom est celle des pronoms objets (me, moi, te, vous).
>   D'autres affirment qu'il n'a aucune fonction grammaticale définie; en
>   effet, on ne peut mettre le pronom en relation logique avec le verbe.
>   Enfin, d'autres grammairiens s'en tirent en disant qu'il s'agit d'un
>   complément d'intérêt.
>
> En fait, le rôle de ces pronoms est davantage énonciatif que
>   grammatical. Ils n'apportent rien au sens de la phrase, à ce qui est
>   dit dans la phrase, ce que font les mots ayant une fonction
>   syntaxique. Mais ils marquent bien l'implication personnelle du
>   locuteur par rapport à ce qu'il dit, à ce qui est énoncé dans la
>   phrase.
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique*, BDL/OQLF - [*pronom d'intérêt*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2927) ]